# Run Program and Config File using Command Line

Tags: java, cmd, config

I have a Java project which comprises of the program named `runProgram` and configuration file named `config.properties` inside the package `pack`. I am trying to run the project as a `.jar` file from the command prompt in Windows 7. But I don't know how to indicate the specific configuration file that I want to use. I tried "open file" with the file name and it didn't work.

**Program:**

```
package pack;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class runProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        double value;
        Properties configFile = new Properties();
        try {
            configFile.load(helloworld.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                "\\pack\\config.properties"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        value = Double.parseDouble(configFile.getProperty("value"));

        System.out.println("Value is: "+value);
    }
}
```

**Config File:**

```
 value = 75
```

Comment: Jar file resources use / as I remember.  Try .getResourceAsStream("/pack/config.properties")  and this will open a file inside your JAR file in subdirectory 'pack'.  Make sure it is there when you create the jar.  What error are you getting if any?  What is displayed when you run this program? How did this "didn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

I give it a shot, but I don't know if I'm getting your question correctly.

> But I don't know how to indicate the specific configuration file that I want to use.

If this is about running the tool, while specifying another config file every time, I'd go with [Apache CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/), to parse and handle command line arguments. Then the user can specify the file every time he/she is running your tool.
(Under 'usage' you can find some examples, but I'm not allowed to post more than two links right now)

But if you want to know more about handling java properties files, here's a good tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Also, for OS independent path definitions, have a look at `System.getProperty("file.separator")`, which, as the name says, tries to receive the OS specific path separator (e.g., '\' for Windows, '/' for UNIX systems).

Hope this helps.